# Importing Multiple CSV files to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, csv, visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to use SSIS Visual Studio 2013 to import 63 CSV files into an empty SQL Server database?

I would like to convert all of my CSV files to SQL Server tables. I know how to do it for one at a time, but I am wondering if there's a way to create a SSIS solution with a loop. I have searched online but couldn't find anything to help me achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the CSV files the same construct?  Or, are they different?  Do you need 63 new tables or can they be INSERT INTO construct?  You are probably going to need to using something like an OPENROWSET - https://answers.laserfiche.com/questions/74591/Auto-Import-csv-into-SQL-Table

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Have a look at https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/ or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqFwTYyy5S0

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies... I followed this tutorial https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/  but i cant find ConnectionString  expression in the dropdown list #Step4

Comment: Btw, you should be using VS 2008 to develop SSIS packages for SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: the CSV files are the same strucuture ?

Comment: No each one is different so I want a new table to be created for each csv

Answer (score 0):

Yes there certainly is a way to do this, it would most likely involve the 'foreach' sequence container. This would iterate through the files and import the data. I can post more later in the day on this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this methodology.  I currently use this technique to bring in multiple csv tables with all sorts of different column configs.

SSIS Package
    Create Table using Stored Procedure
    Bulkload created Table using Stored Procedure

My file configs are stored in my database.  But if you have headers in your csv, you could use SSIS to read the first row and that gives you your field names.

Once you have your field names, if you have a "go-by" template table or a column config lookup table, then it is easy to construct an appropriate SQL statement that dynamically creates your staging table.

The Bulkload is easy in stored procedure and is also dynamic.

Let me know if I can be of any more help.  My stored procedure is too long to post here.